# How to update the evaluation of the responding course if there is multiple subject on a page?(*Cant think of any nice title)

Tags: php, mysqli

Let's say there are 4 results extracted from mysqli query which allow lecturer to evaluate pass/fail for students who registered under this subject.

I am creating another table "result" to store the result which contains course_id, user_id, and results(0: fail,1: pass).

POST method or GET method should I use? I really have no idea how to do it cause all the values is been echoed in a while loop and the data is not preserved.

What I want to achieve is if lecturer click on Pass button in subject A, it should insert data into "results" table with this subject corresponding course_id, the student who registered under this course(user_id) and the results(0/1).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I found myself a solution by generating `<a  type="submit" href=" evaluation_process.php?course_id='.$courseRow['course_id'].' ">Pass</a>` for each subject and I inserting the data in evaluation_process.php by getting the values from $_GET['course_id'] and update my result table in database